# How can I filter an RDD based on length of lines in the dataset.?

Tags: python, apache-spark, filter, pyspark, rdd

> I want to filter out an RDD which is created from a dataset, based on
>   length of line Using: Pyspark shell
>
> My data file looks like this

```
> fzDTn342L3Q   djjohnnykey 599 Music   185 1005    3.67    3   1   KDrJSNIGNDQ MacjQFNVLlQ oZ6f2vaH858 fYSjMDNa4S8 JUatPzf_eSc QfBFl7kU35c rG-rQ-YGdSA kOq6sFmoUr0 IRj1IABVBis AVsZ0VH3eN4 r1pS_4qouUc YgaNW1KRgK4 ZlGdVR7mBy4 nKFLE3DX4OQ EtQjN6CQeCc afe-0VY4YiI ekV5NseEdy8 IQs6CrER5fY jTLcoIxMI-E yfvW1ITcMpM
> 
> kOq6sFmoUr0   djjohnnykey 599 Music   113 992 0   0   1   MacjQFNVLlQ fYSjMDNa4S8 4vso1y_-cvk 8BwAX6YBx3E QeUQyf8H7vM jmc21-Nhewg hZUU2-UBaGk SaLaotssH0w PUlcrBaYpwI tjIK2xop4L0 BNlL15OYnFY _pzP7OLInjk 4daGJ6TMcp4 _8jM9R-1yRk KDrJSNIGNDQ oZ6f2vaH858 JUatPzf_eSc QfBFl7kU35c rG-rQ-YGdSA fzDTn342L3Q
```

> Here the 4th column is category. Some of the lines in the data file
>   does not contain this field and hence less in length.  This motivates
>   me to filter out the data set based on this criteria and further form
>   RDDs on that set of data which has category.
>
> I have tried to create initial RDD from the dataset.

```
>>> data="/Users/sk/Documents/BigData/0222/0.txt"
>>> input = sc.textFile(data)
```

Now I am splitting by tab and saving in lines RDDS

```
>>> lines = input.map(lambda x: (str(x.split('\t'))))
```

After this I want to filter out the lines whose length is less than 3.

```
>>> data="/Users/sk/Documents/BigData/0222/1.txt"
>>> input = sc.textFile(data)
>>> lines = input.map(lambda x: (str(x.split('\t'))))
>>> lines.count()
3169

>>> newinput=input.filter(lambda x: len(x)>3)
>>> newinput.count()
3169
```

> Following this it does not change anything in my rdd. Can anyone
>   please help out.

Comment: You might need to collect() and then count(). Something like 
`newinput=input.filter(lambda x: len(x)>3).collect()` & then
`newinput.count()`

Comment: Could you upload the text file?

Comment: data set can be found here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByJLBTmJojjzR2x0MzVpc2Z6enM/view

Comment: @St1id3r I tried your solution, I got below error : 
`>>> newinput=input.filter(lambda x: len(x)>3).collect()
 >>> newinput.count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things with your solution. Not sure if using RDD is advisable given that this is Python(You might wanna rethink it). Using Dataframes would be easier and performant.

```
>>> x =  spark.read.option("sep","\t").csv("/data/youtubedata.txt")
>>> x.count()
4100
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import length
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import col, size
>>> x.filter(length(col("_c3")) > 3).count()
4066
>>> x.filter(x._c3.isNull()).count()
34
>>> x.filter(x._c3.isNotNull()).count()
4066
```

Update: Updated with counts.

Comment: I tried your solution. But still no change in the number of line  `>>> input = sc.textFile(data)
>>> input.count()
3169 `

Comment: Update my answer wrt to your test data. Also, if you look at the non-nulls counts, that seem to add up the count. Let me know if this works for you.